# Is there an open source solution for full filesystem revision control where the revision db/repository is remote?

Tags: version-control, filesystems

### Question:

Is there a good free & open solution out there for revision control on an entire file system? This includes the question "would any of the typical revision control systems out there work for this (git, svn, bzr, etc.)?"

### Use case:

We have filesystem images that represent installs that happen to some of our embedded systems where every last file installed can make a difference. They often require modification in the course of development, debugging, and maintenance. Those changes need to be stored along with who made them, why, and when. We also need to be able to diff the changes, and restore to particular versions.

Revisioning filesystems would sound like a reasonable compromise. However I can think of a few potential blocking problems:

- commit authentication, and committer & purpose tracking missing
- includes the history in the file system
- hard to commit to shared repository

Comment: Please comment if you're going to downvote and/or vote-to-close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Rsnapshot](http://rsnapshot.org/) and [Bup](https://github.com/apenwarr/bup) both look promising, but I don't have details.

I'm going with Bup, and will update this answer as I have more info.

Comment: Do you have more info?

Answer (score 3):

If anyone else comes across this you might want to look at 
**https://www.presslabs.com/gitfs/**

Answer (score 1):

I *think* what you're asking for is NILFS! It doesn't cover you're whole wishlist, because it is not remote but that maybe could be solved with something like Rsync to another system running nilfs.

Here's why I think you might like it (from the wikipedia Features section):

> NILFS provides continuous snapshotting. In addition to versioning capability of the entire file system, users can even restore files mistakenly overwritten or deleted at any recent time. Since NILFS can keep consistency like conventional LFS, it achieves quick recovery after system crashes.

> Continuous snapshotting is not provided by most filesystems, including those supporting point-in-time snapshotting (e.g. Btrfs)

> NILFS creates a number of checkpoints every few seconds or per synchronous write basis (unless there is no change). Users can select significant versions among continuously created checkpoints, and can change them into snapshots which will be preserved until they are changed back to checkpoints.

Where this might not suit your needs is that I don't believe it stores who made commits or commit log messages. You would have to do something else for that. :/
Further I am not sure if I understand your bullet point "hard to commit to shared repository" Is that saying that you want it to be difficult to commit to a shared repo? or actually that the system of committing to a shared repo will be a hardened process, as in very reliable and consistent for the users?

Answer (score -1):

I think what you want is the SDK/API to access the repository of a certain version control system and perform the actions (like check-in, check-out, show history, etc...)

I am not sure if Git, SVN provide such SDK/API, but I know few commercial version control softwares provide such SDK/API. (e.g. search sourceanywhere SDK in google)

Comment: I think you might misunderstand my question. It's not so much that I want files to be automatically checked in on change, but rather that I'd like to be able to check in a whole filesystem.